# Java: Meaning of non-generic pointer pointing at an generic object?

Tags: java, generics

I'm quite new to Java (and english), so please bear with me.

Tried to write something like...

```
Container con = new Container<Book>();
con.insert(new Book());
con.insert(new Car());
```

...and did not get any type of error. But lines like...

```
Car c = con.remove(); // removes the last inserted element for simplicity
```

said "error: incompatible types", so I changed it to

```
Object carObj = (Car) con.remove();
```

and it worked. My problem is: when I say

```
new Container<Book>();
```

I create a container that can only hold objects of type Book, but because of the pointer (which is non-generic?) I can suddenly put any kinds of objects in my container. What happened here? The pointer only sees the Object-personality in whatever is in the Container, but I didn't know the pointer allowed every object with Object-personality in a container mainly created as generic (my formulation might be wrong). So when I have a non-generic pointer, it doesn't matter whether I create a generic or non-generic container? It will always be considered as a non-generic container (where I have to cast objects when I remove them)?

```
new Container<Book>().insert(new Car()); // compiler error as excepted
```

Got curious and made the problem even worse (maybe).

```
Container<Car> cars = new Container();
cars.insert(new Book()); // compiler error: required Car, found Book
```

Now the pointer only sees the Car-personalities in the container. But it won't allow me to put in a book even though I created the container as non-generic. Why?

```
new Container().insert(new Car()); // works fine
```

Must say, it's both fascinating and irritating...

Answer (score 1):

You're operating on the reference: the reference's type is what will be used at compile time. Inserting a `Book` into a `Container<Car>` is clearly wrong, just as there's nothing wrong with inserting either a `Book` or a `Car` into a `Container`.

Similarly, expecting a `Container.remove` to return a `Car` when the reference is simply `<Container>` is incorrect, because there's no reason to expect the returned object to be a `Car`–it might be a `Book` or a fish.

Answer (score 1):

Your container is a raw container and not a generic container. It's declared as `Container`. It should be declared as `Container<Book>`.

Once done, the line

```
con.insert(new Car());
```

won't compile anymore.

In Java, the generic type of an object is only a compile-time thing. At runtime, due to erasure, it's just a Container. So if you don't declare the container as a `Container<Book>`, you'll have a raw Container and the compiler won't check anything about the type of objects you store inside.

To make it clearer (at least I hope so), the line

```
Container con = new Container<Book>();
```

is equivalent to

```
Container con = (Container) (new Container<Book>());
```

It transforms a reference to a `Container<Book>` into a reference to a raw Container, ruining its type-safety.

Comment: Makes a bit more sense. We were always drawing objects when we learned about this and used lines like 'Container<Book> books = new Container<Book>();' Did not pay much attention to things like what I wrote about above.

Answer (score 0):

Java added generics after there was already lots of code written without generics. The designers of generics wanted to change standard library containers like `List` into `List<X>`, but there was already lots of code written to take just plain `List` that would no longer compile if they'd required all uses to become `List<X>` uses. Furthermore, they wanted people using legacy libraries of their own that, for instance, asked for a `List` and expected it to contain only `String` instances to be able to pass in a `List<String>`.

The way they dealt with this was to introduce the notion of a "raw type" for every generic type, which is basically just the type you get by not writing the angle brackets after a generic type (e.g. `List` instead of `List<String>`). Raw types have different type-checking rules then their non-raw equivalents; for instance if you have a `List` then it's legal to `add` any `Object` into it, but when you `get` something back it comes back as an `Object` that you need to downcast, whereas a `List<String>` will only allow you to `add` a `String`, but in return you don't need to downcast `get`'s result to get a `String` back.

Unfortunately, due to the backwards-compatibility rule that the language designers made, they allowed you to write expessions like

```
List rawList = new ArrayList<String>();
rawList.add(new PeanutButterSandwich());
```

without a compile-time error. You can even do worse things, like

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("string");
List rawList = stringList;
List<PeanutButterSandwich> sandwichList = (List<PeanutButterSandwich>) rawList;
PeanutButterSandwich sandwich = sandwichList.get(0);
```

which compiles (with a warning about an unchecked cast, meaning you made a cast to a generic type from a raw type but the compiler doesn't know that it's legal). Of course this code will definitely raise an exception at runtime since the element in position 0 is a `String`, not a `PeanutButterSandwich`.

What's important to remember is that raw types are only for backwards compatibility, and you shouldn't use them in new code. Also, if you're ever dealing with raw types, be very careful when casting them to generic types, since the compiler can't stop you from doing wrong things.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer =) You're really good at explaining! This definitely clears things up :D I was really wondering why those code-examples did compile even though they had logical errors. I'll leave raw types alone for the sake of learning beginner course in Java.